# How to capture time on click of event start time and event stop time. time difference between open and close event in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date

How to capture time on click of event start time and event stop time. time difference between open and close event. time should display in HH:MM:SS format in Javascript.

Comment: Have you tried any solution? Is it not working?

Comment: Ya I have tried it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var startTime = new Date(today).getTime();
var diff = Date.now() - new Date(startTime).getTime();
var seconds = diff/1000;
var minutes = diff/60000;
var hours = diff/3600000;
var days = diff/86400000;
console.log( days +':'+ hours + ':' + minutes + ":" +  seconds  )
```

Comment: was this meant to be an answer? or was it meant to be in your question?

Comment: This is an answer.